# Force order between two jquery UI sortable lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Surprised this question hasn't been asked before, at least I haven't been able to find it.

I have multiple lists or elements that are all connected together using jQuery UI sortable. Its all working as the docs say it should, however I would like to make the lists force sort. For example, when each list is loaded in, the items are ordered by date. When you move an item from list 1 into list two, you can place that item anywhere in the list, regardless of its date. Similarly you can move items within the same list so they are out of date order.

Is there a way to make it calculate the date ordering and render the items in the correct order once an item has been moved?

Once an item is moved from one list to another it performs an ajax request to save that item to that list, a possible solution would be for that request to return that list in a sorted order and then re-render that list, however that doesnt seem like a particularly clean approach as you already have all the data.

Any easier/better ways of doing this? If its also possible to prevent reordering within the same list that would be ideal.

thanks.

Comment: The whole point of a sortable UI is to let the user reorder items as he likes so you shouldn't be too surprised it hasn't been asked before. Forcing a new sort order on every update breaks this feature. You probably have a scenario where this is needed indeed but you will have to code that part in manually.

Comment: For what you've described, `sortable` is an overkill. You can just use `draggable`/`droppable` and use a `drop` callback to find the correct append position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery Sortable does not handle the behavior you are trying to achieve. You have to do it your self. I think the receive eventHandler is a good starting point. you can use ui.item.prev() and ui.item.next() to retrieve the previous and the next elements then check if the insertion point matches your requirements and insert the element to that position or turn the element back to it's old list/position ( $(ui.sender).sortable("cancel"); )